# JBoss AS7 only works from http://127.0.0.1:8080 on Linux

Tags: java, linux, jboss

`JBoss AS7` only works from `127.0.0.1:8080` on Linux.

I download `jboss-as-7.1.1` and `untar` it.

I then run `bin/standalone.sh` and it starts and if I try to access it from `127.0.0.1:8080` it works great.

but If I try to access it with my computers IP `10.52.206.226:8080/` **it does not work**.

**My Question is:**

1. How can I give other computers access to it?
2. How can I tell Jboss to take requested from all address?

Comment: Read The FAQ Meticulously?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to bind server to your public address. Start your server with command

```
bin/standalone.sh -b 10.52.206.226
```

and binding to all addresses should work too

```
bin/standalone.sh -b 0.0.0.0
```

Answer (score 0):

you can change your hosts file as

```
$ cd /etc
$ sudo gedit hosts
```

just add your ip address as given below:

```
127.0.0.1   localhost
127.0.1.1   someone-pc
192.168.18.75   localhost
```

Use your pc's ip(yourIP) address instead of 192.168.18.75

May it works well.
Now if you try to access
[    http://yourIP:8080]

it will be fine.