# In Jboss server how to configure page index.html to be called from machine ip instead of localhost

Tags: java, windows-7, jboss, jboss7.x, war

I have installed **jboss-as-7.1.1.Final** on my machine, I have *index.html* in my

> C:\jboss-as-7.1.1.Final\standalone\deployments\XYZ.war

file, just wanted to know some way in which i can configure jboss so that i can call index.html from my machine IP instead of localhost like

```
http://127.0.0.1:8090/XYZ/index.html
```

localhost and 127.0.0.1 both works.

Currently it doesn't allow me to access from my machine ip like, http://10.xx.xx.xxx:8090/XYZ/index.html

I am creating the war file from command prompt using ***jar*** command.

any kind of help is appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When starting JBoss you have to bind your server to the ip address:

```
standalone.sh -b [your ip address]
```

Use ip `0.0.0.0` if you want to bind all addresses.

Comment: This question is a duplicate:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13991702/jboss-as7-only-works-from-http-127-0-0-18080-on-linux/13997081#13997081

Comment: Thanks, but i am using windows 7 OS, so i tried below command from command prompt.
> C:\jboss-as-7.1.1.Final\bin>standalone.bat -b 10.90.14.105  
  The error that i am getting is as "Calling "C:\jboss-as-7.1.1.Final\bin\standalone.conf.bat"
'findstr' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file."
can you please tell me what is it that i am doing wrong?

Comment: Try .\standalone.bat -b [ip address]

Comment: Here is what i tried, bin>standalone.bat -b 10.90.14.105        The error that i am getting is as "Calling "C:\jboss-as-7.1.1.Final\bin\standalone.conf.bat" 'findstr' is not recognized as an internal or external command, operable program or batch file."  can you please tell me what is it that i am doing wrong?

Comment: The `findstr` is in **C:\Windows\System32**. Add this path to your windows environment: Go to Computer->System Properties->Advanced System Settings->Environment Variables and below System Variables you have the Path variable. Edit this variable by adding **C:\Windows\System32** at the end.